# Determine number of hours in a given day (plus or minus DST shift hours)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Given an `NSDate` and an `NSCalendar`, how do I determine the number of hours in the day that follows the given date. This would be 23, 24, or 25, depending on whether the following day is entering daylight savings (23), normal (24) or exiting daylight savings (25).

Comment: Have a look at ["Determining Temporal Differences"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW8) in the Date and Time Programming Guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask the calendar how long any unit is (and when that unit starts) with `rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:`.

```
// Test date (the day DST begins)
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.year = 2012;
components.month = 3;
components.day = 11;   

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSTimeInterval dayLength;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:NULL interval:&dayLength forDate:date];
NSLog(@"%f seconds", dayLength);
```

Note that `rangeOfUnit:...` can techincally fail and return `NO`, but if you control the inputs that shouldn't be able to happen.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Test input
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *referenceDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012 03 24 13:14:14"];

// Get reference date with day precision
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:referenceDate];

NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

// Set components to add 1 day
components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = 1;

// The day after the reference date
NSDate *tomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];

// The day after that
NSDate *afterTomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:tomorrow options:0];

// Difference in hours: 23, 24 or 25
NSUInteger hours = [afterTomorrow timeIntervalSinceDate:tomorrow] / 3600;
```